# make div over another on liquid template

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make two div's, one overlaps on another

As you can see on the fiddle below there is `position:relative; top:-20px;` And I would like to make it fully liquid without any `px` maybe on percentage, however I have no Idea how to make that. 
Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pt9uh/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "fully liquid", but those `position` sub-values don't accept percentage values.

The best I could offer is to use

```
#first {
    margin-bottom: -5%;
}
```

or

```
#second {
    margin-top: -5%;
}
```

or some combination thereof.

Comment: however, what is the best way to do stuff like that ?

Comment: I tend to stick to pixel layouts when it comes to margins, padding, and positioning. Percentage values do whacky things when the screen resizes. As an example, put the margins to 20% and adjust your browser height. Watch as the spacing between these elements change. You don't necessarily need to use % values for everything to achieve a liquid layout.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean switching this line as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pt9uh/3/):

```
//top:-20px;
margin-top:-3%;
```